# PHP header not redirecting after mail send

Tags: php

The very end of my code looks like this:

```
mail($to2, $subject2, $body2, $headers2);
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

However, after the `mail` part executes, the page isn't redirected. If I place `var_dump("HI")` in place of the `header` line, it shows up on my page like this: `string(2) HI`, so I know that that section of my code is executing. Why isn't the redirect working?

Comment: there is no output of any kind before the header call?

Comment: Do you get any PHP error? Or do you have any output to the client before the redirect?

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: @AbraCadaver No errors found

Comment: @wigi No errors

Comment: Add an: exit; after the header line.

Comment: Figured out that `header` wasn't working locally (using MAMP), but worked fine when I ran it on an external server. Not sure why though.